# redmine unexpected token ATOM (expected SPACE)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

Ive setup a redmine server 0.9.3 with ruby 1.8.7 on a campus server for my university in order to keep my projects there, but Im getting the following error **unexpected token ATOM (expected SPACE)** when trying to get incoming emails via imap.

How could I fix this?

```
sudo rake redmine:email:receive_imap -f /usr/share/redmine/Rakefile --silent redmine:email:receive_imap unknown_user=accept no_permission_check=1 RAILS_ENV="production" host=imap.uniandes.edu.co port=995 ssl=true username=xxx password=xxx --trace

** Invoke redmine:email:receive_imap (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute redmine:email:receive_imap
rake aborted!
unexpected token ATOM (expected SPACE)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/imap.rb:3129:in `parse_error'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/imap.rb:2981:in `match'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/imap.rb:1961:in `continue_req'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/imap.rb:1948:in `response'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/imap.rb:1876:in `parse'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/imap.rb:1008:in `get_response'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/imap.rb:917:in `initialize'
/usr/share/redmine/lib/redmine/imap.rb:29:in `new'
/usr/share/redmine/lib/redmine/imap.rb:29:in `check'
/usr/share/redmine/lib/tasks/email.rake:133
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:28
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without ssl on, it helped me.

Comment: Works without ssl, but is so insecure that way!